# dojo DataGrid event.cellNode.cellIndex is not returning correct value

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I hava created a editable subGrid ( Grid in grid ) using Dojo DataGrid.
I am fetching and populating the  data in 2nd and 3rd cells  from server based on value in the  1st cell.

event.cellNode.cellIndex giving me correct value in firefox. 
but in IE it is giving some junk number.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Shailaja

Answer (score 0):

```
var cellName=event.cell.name;
```

Fixed the issue to identify the column.